# Item added by Javascript in the dropdown lost after postback from different update panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, html-select

I have two update panel both have the update mode as conditional. In first updatepanel i have 2 dropdown, on selection of first dropdown item being added in 2nd one by javascript. In 2nd update panel i have a button that make postback. After button click it clear the dropdown items added by javascript in first update panel. I did not understand why if the mode is conditional and hit the submit button for different panel still it lost.

Comment: Are you using javascript? If yes, can you please post the code?

Comment: valueDropDown.options.add(new Option("--Select Value--", "0"));
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            valueDropDown.options.add(new Option(result[i], result[i]));
        }

Comment: var valueDropDown = $get("drpDemographicValue");

Comment: You can post it with question too :) anyways see my answer below.

Comment: @Fooker: Are those panel nested?

Answer (score 0):

Because your item is being added on the client side and not server-side.
You have to add your item at the server-side to keep both synched.
Instead of using javascript, add the item at server side and you can use an update panel too.

Comment: try: store it in session variable, while loading page check if session not null, add those back after postback.